Mathematics of a Galton Board
I am watching this video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPhMMnIocR0&list=PL4VRaRxeNj-1F-JukcRVAzbiIi0ibrHqy.
At 11:02, the author shows a simulation and says that for a Galton Board (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton_board), the position and speed of a particle at any given time can be described by the following equations;
$$ x(t + \Delta t) = x(t) + v(t)\Delta t $$
$$ v(t + \Delta t) = v(t) + g\Delta t $$
I am trying to understand these equations better and derive them myself.
Suppose we consider a single falling blue ball and a single fixed red ball. We ignore concepts like friction, air resistance and mass. Given the initial height of the blue ball, the height of the red ball, a coefficient of restitution $\alpha$, the initial angle of the blue ball and the angle of the collision - I am trying to understand where the blue ball will be at any given time.
I tried to derive these equations myself using my limited understanding of Newtonian Physics:
$$ \text{Horizontal Position:} \quad x(t + \Delta t) = x(t) + v_x(t)\Delta t $$
$$ \text{Horizontal Velocity:} \quad v_x(t + \Delta t) = v_x(t) $$
$$ \text{Vertical Position:} \quad y(t + \Delta t) = y(t) + v_y(t)\Delta t - \frac{1}{2}g(\Delta t)^2 $$
$$ \text{Vertical Velocity:} \quad v_y(t + \Delta t) = v_y(t) - g\Delta t $$
$$ \text{Horizontal Velocity after collision:} \quad v_x'(t + \Delta t) = -\alpha \cdot v_x(t) $$
$$ \text{Vertical Velocity after collision:} \quad v_y'(t + \Delta t) = -\alpha \cdot v_y(t) - g\Delta t $$
$$ \text{Horizontal Position after collision:} \quad x'(t + \Delta t) = x(t) + (-\alpha \cdot v_x(t))\Delta t $$
$$ \text{Vertical Position after collision:} \quad y'(t + \Delta t) = y(t) + (-\alpha \cdot v_y(t))\Delta t - \frac{1}{2}g(\Delta t)^2 $$
$$ \text{Angle before collision:} \quad \theta = \arctan\left(\frac{v_y(t)}{v_x(t)}\right) $$
$$ \text{Angle after collision:} \quad \theta' = \arctan\left(\frac{-\alpha \cdot v_y(t)}{-\alpha \cdot v_x(t)}\right) $$
Can someone please help me understand if these equations are correct?
